# What does it mean by: enum constant is a single instance but subclass of a sealed class can have multiple instances?

Tags: kotlin, enums, sealed, sealed-class

I am trying to understand:

[Kotlin Sealed Class Official Doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#:%7E:text=each%20enum%20constant%20exists%20only%20as%20a%20single%20instance%2C%20whereas%20a%20subclass%20of%20a%20sealed%20class%20can%20have%20multiple%20instances%2C%20each%20with%20its%20own%20state.)

But I am struggling to understand the phrase:

> each enum constant exists only as a single instance, whereas a subclass of a sealed class can have multiple instances, each with its own state.

What does that mean? An example will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Enums

You cannot instantiate enum classes yourself. The instances are managed by the language/run-time. So, if you have the following enum class:

```kotlin
enum class Foo(val value: Int) {
    ONE(4), TWO(2)
}
```

Then the only instances of `Foo` are `ONE` and `TWO`. You reference these instances using `Foo.ONE` and `Foo.TWO`. Note that these constants have state (though they don't have to) in the form of the `value` property. But every single reference to `Foo.ONE` will have the same value for `value`, because there is only one instance per constant (i.e., `Foo.ONE === Foo.ONE`). Same with `Foo.TWO`.

---

## Sealed Classes

Sealed classes are different. They restrict the class hierarchy to a known set of classes, but they do not prevent you from instantiating the classes as you need (except for the `sealed` class as they can't be instantiated). For example:

```kotlin
sealed class Foo
class IntFoo(val value: Int) : Foo()
class StringFoo(val value: String) : Foo()
```

With this you can create as many instances of both `IntFoo` and `StringFoo` as you want.

```kotlin
val foo1 = IntFoo(4)
val foo2 = IntFoo(2)
```

That code creates two instances of `IntFoo` (i.e., `foo1 !== foo2`) with different values for `value` (i.e., different state).